# Headless jplayer for game sounds

Tags: javascript, jplayer

Is it possible to use jplayer in a headless fasion suitable for an HTML based game? If so, how? I would like to build playlists and play them in JavaScript.

Comment: You might be able to do it using audio sprites. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jplayer/zlx4N36vWUo but there are a few limitations E.g. Only able to play one sound at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not jPlayer, but I had success with [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/SoundJS#!/SoundJS).